# How can I check SIM lock on Android application level

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to find out if an android device is SIM locked or not. I know that in /efs/ should be a file where this setting is stored at. The problem is that without root there's no access to /efs/.

USSD codes like *#*#7465625# does no more work for Android 4.1.2 on Samsung devices.

So does anybody know how I can figure out if there's a SIM lock enabled?

Thanks, tom

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about the same kind of Sim Lock, you can check SIM Lock and a variety of other things using the [`Telephony Manager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();

if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted returns the state of the installed SIM-card. It doesn't tell if the **device is SIM-locked to a specific network provider**

Comment: Specifically, [the documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED): "`SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED` SIM card state: Locked: requries a network PIN to unlock"