# Android: detect if a device is simlocked by a provider

Tags: android, provider

Is it possible to detect programmatically if an Android device will only work with SIM cards of a certain provider like Versatel / Telecom etc.?

Can I use the following code to perform the check?

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();

if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED) {
    //do something
}
```

I'm not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459470/how-can-i-check-sim-lock-on-android-application-level) addresses the same issue.

Comment: AFAIK it isn't possible to detect if the device is SIM-locked to a specific network provider. The code you have posted checks the state of the SIM-card that is installed in the device. If you install a SIM-card that hasn't been "enabled" yet by the provider, you should see the state `SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.fastgsm.com/en/page/unlock-phone-howto-guide) are some images of what a network lock looks like.

So if the user sees such a screen, then there is a network lock. 
(Or he could try to send an SMS and see if an error message is generated).

Comment: I don't think that would work. I was able to send texts via Wi-Fi using one of those free texting apps.